# How does the method know what variable I'm using? [Java newb]

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

How does my program know what String and array to use? This is my code from my intro to comp sci. We are focusing only on Java. I am having the user enter a sentence and then running that sentence through the method that I created to remove certain char from the sentence and then return it.

The user fills String sentence using the scanner kbd, and ch1, ch2, ch3 get filled from scanner.

When I write the method

```
public static String deletePun(String s, char... arr)
```

how does it know that `sentence = s`, and the `ch1, ch2, ch3` go in `char... arr`

```
package multidimarrayproject;

import java.util.*;

public class multidemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = "";
        char ch1, ch2, ch3;



        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        sentence = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter 3 characters to be removed");
        ch1 = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        ch2 = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        ch3 = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        sentence = deletePun(sentence, ch1, ch2, ch3);
        System.out.println(sentence);









        public static String deletePun(String s, char... arr){      //goes through an removes
                                                            //removes chars entered
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)                     //by the user
    {
        int location = s.indexOf(arr[i]);
        while (location >= 0)
        {
            s = s.substring(0, location) + s.substring(location+1, s.length());
            location = s.indexOf(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? That's just how parameter binding works.

Comment: Because you're passing those variables as arguments in that order when calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

The order the parameters of a method are how the values are passed into the method. You define the method:

```
public static String deletePun(String s, char... arr)
```

and call it:

```
sentence = deletePun(sentence, ch1, ch2, ch3);
```

The first parameter is a `String` and you pass in the value of `sentence` so `s = sentence`. The rest are all characters which are then converted into a `char[]`, `arr = new char[]{ ch1, ch2, ch3 }`.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer: It knows this by the position of the parameters in the call statement. Parameters get pushed onto the call stack in the same order that you pass them during the method call. The called method then pops them from the stack and binds them to the formal method arguments (what's in the parantheses of your `deletePun` definition) by position.

The wait-until-later answer: If you're doing comp sci, you'll probably be doing an introduction to machine level languages, a.k.a. assembler, not too far into the future. I can promise you that everything about how high level languages like Java work will become much clearer then.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying all of these things in the line `sentence = deletePun(sentence, ch1, ch2, ch3);`
This makes sentence equal to the result of the method call `deletePun(String s, char... arr)` into which you're passing `sentence`, `ch1`, `ch2` and `ch3`.